# Roles assignement in Symfony 2

Tags: php, security, symfony, roles

I try to assign role to user in my controller. For example in database I getting this result `a:1:{i:0;s:11:"ROLE_DRIVER";}`, but when somewhere in my app I try do this

```
if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_DRIVER')) {
```

I always get false. In profiler I see that current user has `ROLE_USER` instead of `_DRIVER`.
Where is my problem ? Here is my role assign:

```
$user->setRoles(array(1 => 'ROLE_DRIVER'));
```

User config:

```
# FOSUserBundle configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
            form:
                type: vputi_user_registration
    profile:
            form:
                type: vputi_user_profile
    change_password:
             form:
                type: vputi_user_change_password
                name: vputi_user_change_password
```

When in twig I do this:

```
{% if user.roles[0] == 'ROLE_DRIVER' %}
```

All works fine, but in Controller...

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle ? Can you provide some code of your User object, some configuration about your security ?

Comment: Yes i using FOSUserBundle. I add my config to question body.

Comment: Have you logged persisted the user object, logged out and then back in again?

Comment: yes. nothing happened.

Comment: maybe it's better if we could also see the implementation of roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to do this for assigning the `ROLE_DRIVER`

```
$user->addRole('ROLE_DRIVER');
```

Or you can change the way you are giving it a value to:

```
$user->setRoles(array("ROLE_DRIVER"));
//update user
```

Updates:

```
$user->addRole('ROLE_DRIVER');
$user->addRole('ROLE_OLD_DRIVER');
```

this is the same as setting this two roles in one line:

```
$user->setRoles(array("ROLE_DRIVER", "ROLE_OLD_DRIVER"));
```

Twig checks:

```
{% if app.user.hasRole('ROLE_FOO') %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: hello, I dont know how, but when I try your code today all works! Thanks)

Comment: How are you assigning multiple roles?

Comment: multiple roles? no. I assign one role.